# How to only show tableau column subtotals

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to show only column subtotals in Tableau. When I select analysis>"show subtotals", the row subtotals show up as well. Can someone please advise on a way to hide the row subtotal column?

Comment: Can you just create ad hoc groups of items?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the caret at the right side of the field on the row or column shelf corresponding to the subtotals you wish to turn off. When you see the list of menu commands, uncheck subtotals for that field

Answer (score 0):

**To get subtotals of all categories**

1.Go to Analysis > Totals > Subtotals and also uncheck Rowtotals

### Refer this link to do :https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6XbC.png

2.while following above steps you will get desired result.